# IP traffic over Bluetooth in Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, ip, tethering

I would like to create an app that communicates with a device through Bluetooth.

I want to use a mobile app in order to pair and connect with some hardware (containing a Bluetooth server) and be able to query that device to get its status and other info. I would like to do this by sending IP traffic over Bluetooth (https get/post requests).

In order to achieve the above (IP traffic over BT) this would require pairing with the other device and connecting to the PAN (Personal Area Networking) profile. Is my understanding correct?

Does Android natively provide any API to achieve the above? After some investigation, it seems that Android only provides a hidden API which is accessible only via reflection in order to achieve the connection to the PAN profile. Is there any other proper way to do this?

Also, what happens if user connects to WiFi or LTE? Am I still able to send IP traffic via bluetooth if  WiFi or LTE is enabled at the same time?

Finally, is there any other approach you may have in mind that would be safer and would make better sense to follow?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any solution you found?